# Broken y-axis in multiple y-axis settings for Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have the first chart:

[Multiple y-axis with broken y-axis for left-hand-side y-axis only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYlb0.png)

The left-hand-side y-axis is broken from 1M to 25M, while there is no broken setting for the right-hand-side y-axis. The horizontal lines for the 2 y-axis in the chart area make it a little bit hard to read. It can be improved by setting the broken for the right-hand-side y-axis from 250K to 6.25M like the 2nd chart shows:

[Multiple y-axis with broken y-axis for both y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o526.png)

The broken setting is set by user. They cannot preview the result when configuring the settings.

I want to have a chart with the horizontal lines for both hand side overlapped with each other. I can only add the broken setting for right-hand-side y-axis. But I should know the min & max value for all the series used. The min value is default to be 0, but the max value for the series which use left-hand-side y-axis is around 44M, while it is around 13.5M for the right-hand-side y-axis. But the chart shows me 56M for the left-hand-side y-axis, while it is 14M for the right-hand-side y-axis. I cannot predict the max value for the y-axis while generating the chart setting.

Is it possible to add the broken setting for the right-hand-side programmatically? Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add the broken setting for the right-hand-side
> programmatically? Or is there any other approach?

Yes, adding programmatically calculated breaks seems to be the only way. You can use for example chart's load event where you have access to all the required values.

For example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const yAxes = this.yAxis;

        yAxes[1].update({
          breaks: [{
            from: 20,
            to: 40,
            breakSize: 0
          }]
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s01box6p/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks

Comment: This approach is Okay, but the main problem for this approach is the value range I pointed out in the post. I cannot easily get the value range according to my values in the series. The maximum value is around 44M in my series, while the y-axis maximum value is 56M in the first chart (for the left hand side y-axis).

Comment: You can get all the required values from the chart (`this` in a load function) and calculate breaks programmatically.